# golang database Open function ambiguity

Tags: sql, sqlite, go

In go, you invoke a database open with

```
DB, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", "./bar.db")
```

This returns a database of type `*sql.DB`, the function and type are both members of `database/sql`.

However, in the sqlite3 driver package, there is another `Open` function which returns a `*sqlite3.Conn` type.

I've noticed that some of the functions defined in the `sqlite3` driver package do not work on a database opened using the default `database/sql`.

Additionally, there are functions in the sqlite3 package that are similar to `database/sql`'s functions, namely `Query` and `Exec`, which return different types.

`database/sql` contains a func `Query` that returns type `*sql.Rows`.

`mxk/sqlite/sqlite3` and `mattn/go-sqlite3` both have a `Query` function, which return completely different types.

I want to run functions such as `mxk/sqlite/sqlite3`'s `BusyTimeout` on my database connection, but it isn't the correct type. Do I have to re-write all of my code to open the database connection with the sqlite3 driver instead of using `database/sql`'s `Open`? What's the advantage of `database/sql`'s `Open` function if you can't use any of the driver's functions with that generic connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as the [docs](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-sqlite/go1/sqlite3) state...

> Database connections are created either by using this package directly or with the "sqlite3" database/sql driver. The direct interface, which is described below, exposes SQLite-specific features, such as incremental I/O and online backups. The driver is recommended when your application has to support multiple database engines.

... you would use the sqlite3 connection when you want the *sqlite specific* functions (your usecase) and  for generic database connections you would use the database driver (your code).

That is perfectly logical, since how would a generic driver handle functions that are specific to various databases? Runtime errors?

So you have a choice: all sqlite functions -> sqlite conn or handle multiple sql databases -> generic driver.